# How to use Group Policy to force user compliance

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy

I need recommendations for using group policy to restrict a user's computer/network access until the user takes an action, in this case acknowledging he has read an acceptable use policy.

The user will be in a group containing users who have not complied. Upon completion he will be removed.

What are good ideas for using Group Policy to limit what this user can do, or to annoy them with popups, to 'force' the user to comply? A link to appropriate code would be greatly appreciated, or the code itself if possible.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The generally accepted practices are:

1. Use a login banner.  This would have to be somewhat concise, but the user cannot login until they click "OK".  The legal enforceability of this (or any popup) may vary by jurisdiction.
2. Make them sign the Acceptable Use Policy before they're given their username/password. This is highly enforceable, since it's basically a signed contract. If this is a new AUP, then reset their password and don't give them the new one until they have signed.

Comment: This is the approach we use, the login banner text includes by logging into this system you agree to the acceptable use policy blah blah blah.

Answer (score 3):

This is not at all what Group Policy is designed to do.

I think the closest thing to what you are asking for is Network Access Control / Network Admission Control / 802.1x. These solutions are vendor-specific. Microsoft has one, Cisco has one... other vendors do too.

You can do neat things like put the user in a "quarantine network" unless that user has a certain flag on their account, like an attribute, or maybe a registry key on their client, or anything like that... in your case, that "flag" would signify that the user has accepted your terms of usage. Then they will automatically be allowed into the regular network access policy.

Again, this is not something you will ever be able to do with Group Policy alone.

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned the banner login would do part of what you're asking for. It would tell them a message but they don't really have a "cancel" option. They only get "ok". Another thing you could do but requires more work is to write a script during login that will give them a popup message with yes or no and perhaps take up the whole screen. Then depending on the choice selected it could write to a file and record the choice. If they said "yes" then the next time the script would ignore giving the message again. If they clicked no the script could log them off the pc.